# How to export a configuration of MS Project 2013 so that I can import it in another file ?

Tags: ms-project-2013

I have multiple projects to handle. And I make some personalized fields for one of those project under MS Project 2013.

I would like to export my configuration and use it in another file. is this possible ?

for example :

- in **FILE1.mpp** I made a personalized field called **NumberOfTasks**
- I want to import that to **FILE2.mpp** without having to go through the same steps that I have done to make the **NumberOfTasks** formula ?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy custom formulas using the Organizer.  Open both files and use File > Info and click Organizer.